# "After being broken up" vs. "After broken up"

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between these two sentences?

> - "After being broken up with my boyfriend"
> - "After broken up with my boyfriend"

Why we use "being" in the first sentence? I saw it on Gossip Girl Season 1 Episode 8 at 02:06 she said "after being broken.."

Comment: Both of them are wrong. It should be: *"After having broken up with my boyfriend."*

Comment: I would hesitate to give an opinion, because I have not come across either form. What I usually see is: 'After breaking up with...' and 'After I broke up with...'. What are the sources of your examples?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the two phrases mean (neither of them is a sentence)  because they are not normal English. I _think_ you are asking for the difference between "...after having been broken up with by my boyfriend..." and "...after breaking up with my boyfriend...", but it's not really clear.

Comment: The first sentence can be amended to "After being broken up with BY my boyfriend" to mean that he broke up with you, if that is what is meant.

Comment: Nothing. Both wrong. "After breaking up with my boyfriend..." (if you left him), or "After my boyfriend broke up with me..." (if he left you).

Comment: I saw it on Gossip Girl Season 1 Episode 8 at 02:06 she said "after being broken.."

Comment: You haven't provided enough of the dialogue in the scene you've referenced. As it stands, it's poor English. But it would be correct English to say "After being broken up with my boyfriend for two months, we got back together” (although we might quibble about whether it should be hyphenated as "broken-up"). “After broken up with my boyfriend” is always wrong in all contexts.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of

> - "After being broken up with my boyfriend"
> - "After broken up with my boyfriend"

is correct English. "To break up with someone" is to end a romantic and/or sexual relationship. (More rarely it can mean to end a non-romantic  friendship.) One does not say "being broken up with" but rather "having broken up with" or "I broke up with" to indicate that this happened in the past. "break up with" is a verb phrase in this usage. It would not be used with "being" in any tense. For a construction with "being" one would use an -ed form, such as "being separated from"

Without context I cannot be sure, but I suspect the original was simply an informal, incorrect usage. It is not a common enough usage to become correct by virtue of usage.